# Django models many to many relations

Tags: django, django-models

I'm moving my first steps with django and I'm trying to figure out a thing.
Suppose that we have a `model.py` made like this where `NameEffect` has a many to many relation

```
class Name(models.Model):
    nameid = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Effect(models.Model):
    effectid = models.IntegerField()
    effect = models.TextField()

class NameEffect(models.Model):
    nameid = models.IntegerField()
    effectid = models.IntegerField()
    start = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    strand = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and I want to create a QuerySet where every entry contains `name,effect,start,strand` of the researched name. Fact is that the only solution I found was using raw SQL queries but I can't understand how to do it with the django models approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined any relationships here at all. You should identify the fields as ForeignKeys - and also define the implicit many-to-many relationship explicitly (although you don't actually need it for this particular query, but it'll definitely come in useful).

```
class Name(models.Model):
    nameid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    effects = models.ManyToManyField('Effect', through='NameEffect')

class Effect(models.Model):
    effectid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    effect = models.TextField()

class NameEffect(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('Name', db_column='nameid')
    effect = models.ForeignKey('Effect', db_column='effectid')
    start = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    strand = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now you can can query NameEffect directly to get the result you want.

```
data = NameEffect.objects.values('name__name', 'effect__effect', 'start', 'strand')
```

Also note, unless you know you really need just these fields, you should avoid using `values` and just query NameEffect using `select_related`:

```
name_effects = NameEffect.objects.select_related('name', 'effect')
```

and then access the values when you need them, eg in a template:

```
{% for obj in name_effects %}
    {{ obj.name.name }}
    {{ obj.effect.effect }}
    {{ obj.start }}
    {{ obj.strand }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the wrong models.py but i typed it quickly just to have a base for the example. Thanks a lot again